# how to remove specific element from stack?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

How can I Remove an element from stack  for example
1 2 3 4 5 6
remove(List , 3)
the stack will be like this after deletion 1 2 3

```
public static void removeElements(LinkedStack<Integer> list , int x){

    LinkedStack<Integer> list2  = new LinkedStack<>();
 
 
    
  while(!list.isEmpty()){
   int temp = list.pop();
    
    if(temp == x){

      list.pop();
    }
    list2.push(temp);
    
  }
  
  while(!list2.isEmpty()){
      list.push(list2.pop());
  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should  add x to the second list and add the subsequent elements  like bellow :

```
public static void removeElements(LinkedStack<Integer> list, int x) {

        LinkedStack<Integer> list2 = new LinkedStack<>();
        boolean found=false;

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            int temp = list.pop();

            if (temp == x || found) {
                found=true;

                list2.push(temp);
            }
        }

        while (!list2.isEmpty()) {
            list.push(list2.pop());
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you sir but i want it to delete the elements until it reaches the specified element and when it reaches the specified element it will give me the list without the deleted elements

Comment: i have edited my answer to take into account your explanation

Comment: Sorry but the whole thing still makes no sense. If `x` is set to a nonexisting value on the stack, all values from the stack get deleted. So the stack `list2` is superflous. 
The question is *how to remove specific element from stack?* but precisely that element `3` gets not deleted.
Finally, I would call a `LinkedStack` stack rather than list.